# Distance measure for ordinal data (multiple measures)

Tags: clustering, ordinal-data, distance

I have collected user ratings for 4 different ordinal variables. Variable A has (likert) scale from 1-7 but can be collapsed to 1-3, Variables B, C, D have (likert) scale from 1-4.

For each item, x (a text comment) - I have 5 different ratings for each ordinal variable (from 5 different users). There is some missing data so for some items (text comments) there are only 4 or 3 ratings.

I am hoping to cluster these comments with the objective of visualizing any natural variance in the text samples but also the variation introduced by multiple, subjective judgments.

My questions are:

1. What is a good distance measure for ordinal data that suits this use case?
2. Since I have multiple observations for each comment - should I aggregate them? Aggregating them will smooth over the noise. Is there any way I can account for all user ratings while I try to cluster the comments?

I was planning on tackling one ordinal variable at a time i.e., clustering based on one ordinal variable at a time. For example, with variable A - I can come up with vectors. Rating - 1 -> (1, 0 , 0), 2 -> (0, 1, 0), 3 -> (0, 0, 1).

But a given comment has 5 different vectors for variable A. If I sum them over I might get a resultant vector that looks like this -> (1, 4, 0). Should I sum it over? Using measures like Kendall Distance does not seem to make sense here since 4 now represents not a ranking, but strength of agreement on ranking 2.

Are there other techniques to find distance/dissimilarity measure? Other techniques I can use here to cluster my data?